# Div Scroller Top & Down Button

Tags: jquery

I want to add 2 buttons on my site to scroll top and down Div id. The only thing which I want to know is:  what would I write to tell button to scroll top or down once clicked? I already have the script for scrolling animation.

Check out this website I am looking to do exactly the same.
http://www.mecomed.com/

Answer (score 1):

They are using the [jQuery.ScrollTo plugin by Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

1. Press F12 to open the console - or right-click the "down" button and do "Inspect element"
2. The button doesn't have an ID but have a class "down" so it's likely queried using the class name
3. Go to "scripts" tab in the console and look the scripts loaded - you'll find "default.js" one (most likely the one scripting the page)
4. Search for ".down" and you'll find the binding to the click event.

Here's their code:

```
$("#scroller a.down").bind("click", function() {
    $currpage = $("#content > div[id='" + location.hash.replace("#", "") + "']");
    if ($currpage.attr("id") != $lastchild.attr("id")) {
        $nextpage = $currpage.next();

        // here it is
        $.scrollTo($nextpage, 800, {
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            offset: {
                top: -105
            }
        });

        location.hash = $nextpage.attr("id");
    }
    return false;
});
```